# Only Allow specific country to connect server (Google cloud platform)

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, ddos

Create a VM instance on GCP (linux server)
How could i set only specific country allowed to connect to the server to prevent DDOS  (not website)
Or is there any other way to prevent?
[network status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZpbI.png)

Comment: Your image does not show a DDoS attack. 23 Mbytes is not significant. There are several things to note: 1) Geo scoping IP addresses is not reliable 2) If a bad actor wants to take down your site they will. 3) You will need to deploy resources that cost money (firewalls, WAFs, load balancers, etc).

Comment: Do you want a public access (by anybody, without authentication) from a specific country? Can you add more detail on this requirement (legal?)?

Comment: i created 2 vm on GCP, 1 is for website , and 1 is for gaming server .
This is the network status of my gaming server in this few hours .
(https://imgur.com/PtCvEVg)

Comment: Screenshots do not help. We would need to know what ports they are attempting connections to. What is your firewall configuration? You can block significant traffic by disabling ports.

Answer (score 1):

Google provides a managed service for anti-DDOS measures - [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/). You can filter incoming requests by [IP address, IP range, region code, request headers](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-concepts#overview) and such. Take a look at the [pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/armor/pricing) for it as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you need network-level IP address blocking/blacklist capability, you should add load balance and limit IP range of each country you want to block their access.
You can also config it with WAF or any firewall you have installed on your linux server.